# Обработка ошибок AXIOS post Vue3+Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, axios, vue3

Отправляется post запрос в laravel если искомая техника не найдена выдаётся ошибка 500 и возвращается текст ошибки. Но во vue почему то ошибка не срабатывает и заходит в then.

Запрос:

```
async postAnalogByGarageNumber() {
                try {
                    this.loaded = false
                    this.showSpinner = true
                    this.searchedPart = []
                    this.repairListsData = []
                    const request = await axios.post('api/analogGarageNumber', {
                        materials: this.newInputs.materials,
                        garageNumber: this.newInputs.garageNumber,
                    })
                    console.log(request)
                    this.partsData = request.data
                    this.loaded = true;
                } catch (error) {
                    if (error.response && error.response.status === 500) {
                        // Здесь обрабатываем ошибку 500
                        console.log('Ошибка 500:', error.response.data);
                    } else {
                        // Обработка других ошибок
                        console.log('Ошибка:', error.message);
                    }
                }
            }
```

API:

```
Route::post("/analogGarageNumber", [AnaloguesController::class, "getAnalogByGarageNumber"]);
```

Контроллер:

```
public function getAnalogByGarageNumber(Request $request)
        {
            try {
                return response()->json($this->analogService->getAnalogByGarageNumber($request->garageNumber ?? "", $request->materials ?? ""), 200);
            } catch (TestException $exception) {
                return response()->json(
                    [
                        'message' => $exception->getMessage()
                    ], 500);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Вы используете async/await, и при этом ловите ошибку. Так Вы получаете успешное выполнение промиса. Или промисифицируйте внутри код ещё раз и возвращайте `reject`, или сразу же на `catch` отправляйте `exception`, тогда наверху у Вас отработает `catch`, а не `then`

Comment: @VladimirGonchar Я получаю выполнение промиса из-за чего выполняется код внутри then и выдаёт не ту ошибку которую я отправил ошибка, которую выдает мне данный запрос: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

Comment: тогда покажите полностью код и саму ошибку (в смысле это от `console.log('Ошибка:', error.message);` или внутренняя ошибка)

Comment: @VladimirGonchar От console.log, просто кода с бэка отправляется статус 500 ни один из catch не работает а запрос выполняет then и ссылается на то что в res нет указанных свойств, хочу сделать вывод своих ошибок возможно не правильно делаю обработку ошибок на vue3

Comment: Тогда нужно всё же делать то, что я говорил выше. Просто после `console.log` выкидывайте exception наверх с данными. Ну и вообще, проверяйте код на валидность, `request.data` - undefined, тогда делайте обработку на проверку данных.

Comment: А в глобальном смысле это всё не очень полезно, потому что на каждый запрос такое делать будет грустно. Посмотрите в сторону axios interceptors

Comment: А где здесь валидация `Request` ?